# How to preserve python colorama color output when using tee on Windows

Tags: python, windows, tee, colorama

In my Windows 10 scenario, I want to print arbitrary python console output (`print()`, `sys.exit()`, etc) both to console and a log file. I don't have control over some parts of the code (external python packages), so I cannot use some dedicated logging mechanism.

After some research I found the tool *tee.exe* in UnxUtils which does this task almost the way I want.

My problem is to preserve color as generated by python's *colorama* package. Is there any way to accomplish that? Currently, tee.exe strips away the color.

The answer I am looking does not have to rely on tee.exe, it's just the closest I got to a real solution. What I am looking for should do the following:

- any command line output appears both in the command line and the log file (both STOUT and STDERR)
- the output appears on the command line in real time. Bonus points if this is also true for the log file.
- color is preserved on the command line. Bonus points if the log file does not contain any color-related artifacts.

What I have so far is this:

Python file *teetest.py*:

```
import sys
import colorama

print("Test")
print("2nd Test")

colorama.init(autoreset=True)
print(colorama.Fore.RED + 'Color Test')
colorama.deinit(autoreset=True)

sys.exit("Error_Test")
```

Batch file *teetest.bat*:

```
@echo off
python teetest.py 2>&1 | tee log.txt
pause
```

My output looks like this (command line and log file are identical, no color):

```
Test
2nd Test
Color Test
Error_Test
```

The solution I am looking for will print the above to the command line so the words **Color Test** are red.

**Edit:**

It seems that `tee.exe` is not at fault. Instead, colorama strips away the ANSI characters for color control by design, so the color is lost when passed through `tee.exe`.

From the colorama manual:

> Colorama makes this work on Windows, too, by wrapping stdout, stripping ANSI sequences it finds (which would appear as gobbledygook in the output), and converting them into the appropriate win32 calls to modify the state of the terminal.

Colorama's `init()` function offers the parameter `strip`, which if `False`, does cause colorama to not strip away the ANSI characters. This in turn allows to write a custom `tee.py` that does the same as `tee.exe`, as outlined by user @martineau below. In it, we can call colorama and handle the color properly.

This might be a workable solution, but it still has the downside that I would have to replace all colorama `init()` calls with `init(strip=False)` in my original python code and that in turn would cause ANSI characters to appear in the output if the code was called without redirecting through `tee.py`.

This might actually be the closest we can get to a proper solution here. If anyone can offer other ideas, I'm all ears but I fear chances are slim.

Comment: Just a quick question: you assume `tee` strips ANSI sequences, but did you actually *test* that? `colorama` *itself* is terminal-aware: "The default behaviour is to strip if on Windows or if output is redirected (not a tty)." [github/colorama](https://github.com/tartley/colorama).

Comment: @usr2564301. Maybe I didn't phrase this properly. I don't think `tee` strips the ANSI sequence, but in fact, colorama does. See my comment on martineau's answer. I meant to integrate this information into the original post, but haven't gotten around to it yet. A solution might be to use colorama's `strip` argument, however that would force me to adapt the python code, something I would like to avoid.

Comment: If you are looking for a change with minimal impact to *your* code, you could always change your local copy of `https://github.com/tartley/colorama/blob/master/colorama/initialise.py` to have `strip` cleared by default.

Comment: @usr2564301 Thanks for the idea. I actually throught about hacking colorama in a similar way and finding out about `strip` makes it pretty easy to do. Still it would be very cool to have an option the works the same way regardless of whether I pipe my output through `tee` or not. At this point I have little hope though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it will work with respect to `colorama`, but after being unsatisfied with several `tee` utilities for Windows that I found online, I ended up writing my own in Python (3.x).

You may have to modify it to suit your own needs, but it should be a good start.

**`mytee.py`**:

```
"""
    Copies stdin to stdout (screen) *and* the specified file.
"""
import fileinput
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

SHOW_FULL_PATH = False
DIVIDER = True
DIV_CH = ' '

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    raise SystemExit('Usage: mytee <filepath>')

try:
    inp = fileinput.input(())  # Read from stdin.
    path = Path(sys.argv[1])
    stdout_write = sys.stdout.write
    stdout_flush = sys.stdout.flush
    # Assumes .py in same dir as output file.
    script = (f'{path.parent/path.stem}{path.suffix}' if SHOW_FULL_PATH else
              f'{path.stem}{path.suffix}')

    with open(path, 'w') as outp:  # Write to specified file.
        outp_write = outp.write
        outp_flush = outp.flush

        def write(line):
            stdout_write(line)
            outp_write(line)

        def writeln(line):
            write(line + '\n')

        banner = f'"{script}"' if ' ' in script else f'-[{script}]-'
        writeln(f'{banner}')
        if DIVIDER:
            writeln(f'{DIV_CH * len(banner)}')
        for line in inp:
            write(line)
        if DIVIDER:
            writeln(f'{DIV_CH * len(banner)}')
        writeln('-[done]-')
finally:
    inp.close()  # Not sure this is really necessary.

sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: That's a pretty cool idea! From my test run with your code it seems to strip away the color information as well. It's likely that colorama consumes the color information upon print so that part is never passed to stout. Maybe I can find another way in python to capture that data. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Windows' piping command, `|`, could be what's stripping the color information.

Comment: There may be a way, based on your solution. colorama.init() has the optional attribute "strip". If set to False, it will leave control characters in place. So if I add a colorama.init() to your code and replace colorama.init() by colorama.init(strip=False) in mine, then it works. It's still not ideal, since I have to change my code to accomodate the change but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Cerno: It's good to hear my "one off" utility turned out to be useful to someone else. Feel free to post your own answer with the changes in it that support `colorama` for others to use.